# How to enhance window size selection on a tkinter project including button-image as label?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm currently working on a little project on python-3.x including some tkinter ressources. My program is made to display on a screen a list of pictures included in a directory, each picture is put on a button that is a sixth of the original image, and if we click on it, it display the image on his original size on a new window. The original window is set by the amount of pictures i put in the columns (i can choose in the code) and i ve made a scrollbar because i have to work with a lot of pictures.

But here is my problem, it's works fine except that if i change the window size, like reduce it for example, the buttons don't follow, they just vanish behind the window, and with the scrollbar.

I'm not particularly good in python so i was wondering that maybe by doing like a threading we could get the window size in live and then if the window size is inferior/superior of our columns of buttons, we could resize it and change the amount of columns then reload the page, but i will have to work with multiple image so it will take a lot of time.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import glob
import os
import cv2
import copy
import _thread
import time

folder = 'X:/users/Robin/data/dataset-valid/visu/*.jpg'  

a=glob.glob(folder)

fic = "../data/list.txt"

fichObj=open(fic,"w")

p = []

for f in a:
    fichObj.write(f+"\n")
fichObj.close()

class SuperPhoto(object):
        def __init__(self, photo , image):

                self.photo = photo
                temp = cv2.resize(image, (int((self.photo.width())/6) , int((self.photo.height())/6))) 
                red = temp[:,:,2].copy()
                blue = temp[:,:,0].copy()
                temp[:,:,0] = red
                temp[:,:,2] = blue
                temp = Image.fromarray(temp)
                self.miniature = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)

        def agrandir(self):
                Newfen=Toplevel() 
                Newfen.geometry("+60+60")
                #self.photo.resize((500,500))


                print(type(self.photo))
                label = Label(Newfen, image=self.photo, width=self.photo.width(), height=self.photo.height())
                label.image = self.photo # keep a reference!
                label.pack()


if os.path.exists (fic):     #os.path utile 
        count = len(open(fic).readlines())    
        print(count)
        #lin = open(fic).readlines()
        #print(lin)


class ScrollableCanvas(Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        canvas=Canvas(self,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))

        canvas.update_idletasks() 

        vbar=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        canvas.config(width=1200,height=700)
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior, anchor=NW )

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

class Main_frame(Frame):
    # Init
    def __init__(self, fenetre_principale=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, fenetre_principale)
        self.grid()
        self.scrollable_canvas = ScrollableCanvas(self)
        self.scrollable_canvas.grid(row=1,column=1)         

        nbCol = 4

        for file in a:
                image = Image.open(file)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                w = photo.width()
                L.append(int(w/6))
                #print(L)
                sumL = int(sum(L)/nbCol)

                print(sumL)

                p.append(SuperPhoto(photo, cv2.imread(file)))

        for ligne in range(int(count/nbCol)):
                for colonne in range(nbCol):
                        photo = p[ligne * nbCol + colonne]    
                        button = Button(self.scrollable_canvas.interior, image=photo.miniature, command=photo.agrandir)
                        button.grid(row=ligne, column=colonne)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("VISU")
    root.geometry("+0+0")
    L= []    


    interface = Main_frame(fenetre_principale=root)
    root.update_idletasks() 
    print(root.winfo_width())
    print(root.geometry())
    interface.mainloop()
```

So, I except this program to work like a classic directory display, with the columns that change automatically when we resize the window and with the scrollbar that follow it.

If you have any solutions it will really help me ..

You can try it, just put some jpeg pictures in a directory and change the folder variable with the link of your directory.

Thanks in advance for your help, if you have any questions to understand more clearly what  i've said don't hesitate.

Comment: when the window size is changed, a `<Configure>` event is thrown. Maybe all you need to do is to update the window each time it is resized? Handle the event using a callback function and then update the root window there. Hope this helps

Comment: yup thanks, but i will have to deal with 50 to 200 pictures so i can't just reload the main window each time i resize it, it will take too much time (~20 sec to show 40 pictures right now).

Comment: you are not reloading the root window, but updating it each time you dynamically resize it. The update should re-grid your buttons. The images will not change their size if the `cv2.resize` option is not recalled in the callback function

Comment: alright, thanks. But i'm still a beginner in python, do you think you can help me with code example ? I'm not sure to understand everything you said ..

Answer (score 0):

Each time the `root` window is resized, a `<Configure>` event is triggered. Catch it as follows:

```
def resize(event):
    root.update_idletasks()
    #update all image sizes here if needed
    #all widgets can be 're-grided' here based on new width and height of root window

root.bind('<Configure>', resize)
```

If you want to ensure that your window cannot be resized, use the following:

```
root.resizable(False, False)
```

Comment: Okay, i ve try it on my program, it allow to get back the size of the window in live, but how can i reload my label with the new size of the window ? (without having to reload completely my program with the new width)

And no .. i really need the window to allow the changement of size ... Thanks!

Comment: which labels do you want to 'reload'? the code line `root.update_idletasks()` should update all widgets (nested or not) on the root window. And just out of curiosity, in your code why does your `__init__` have 2 functions in it?

Comment: the buttons, all my images are in fact button. 

It didn't update it, when i try to change the size of my root window say stick at their places. 

It wasn't me that write this part of code, ive found on stackoverflow, it's just to allow the scrollbar to work (The only solution ive found to make a functional scrollbar...)

Comment: Hi, up ! Anyone ?